# Can't handle false or exception from imagecreatefromstring

Tags: php

How i can handle exception or return 'false' from php function imagecreatefromstring. In code below, i'm tried to trigger false is just broking and do not return false when im trying to load zip for example.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//zip file
 $stringImage = $file->getStream()->getContents();
    if (false === imagecreatefromstring($stringImage)){
        echo CJSON::encode(new JSONError('Error'));
}
```

result of that:

> imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

Comment: Was resolved by add "@" before function

@imagecreatefromstring

Comment: That only hides the error/warning/notice output.

Answer (score 0):

Full spec https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

I am leaving a sample code. I hope it will be handy to you.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zHandle = $zip->open(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "contains.png.zip");
// $zHandle = $zip->open(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "contains.txt.zip");
if($zHandle && $zip->numFiles == 1){
    $im_string = $zip->getFromName($zip->statIndex(0)['name']);
    $zip->close();
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($im_string);


    // That's what you care about...
    $err = error_get_last();
    if ($err['type'] ==  2) {
        echo "\nWe have a warning ...";
        echo "\nMessage:".$err['message'];
        echo "\nFile:".$err['file'];
        echo "\nLine:".$err['line'];
        return;
    }

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
} else {
    throw new \Exception("Ups ... check your handle or check the real number of zipped files.", 1);
}
```